# Cross Document/Window AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am in the process of building a packaged chrome application and was wanting to use Angular. Being a local application that has ui behaviors similar to a native application, I wanted to make use of multiple windows for popups and different workflows. This would be more intuitive to the user as opposed to dialog boxes or modals.

Is there a good angular way of sharing service instances amongst these windows? Is there a different solution that I am not seeing?

**Update**

To be a little more clear, I am wanting to share data between javascript windows. There is the basic `window.postMessage` but I would like to be able to share service instances between these two separate windows.

**Possible Solution**

I have found a hack to share services and posted an answer below. I'd love thoughts on it. What might be more ideal is if I could share the `$injector` service itself. That would probably take care of all possible options and make it as if it were in the same app. I believe the `$injector` has reference to the rootElement in the DOM which would of course be different in the new window so that solution may not work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to come up with a way to share services across multiple windows but it is still a bit clunky and would prefer a better solution if available.

In your parent window as a chrome app, you would launch a new window with the following code.

```
  chrome.app.window.create("view2.html", options, function(window){

    //This function is a callback that is called when the child 
    //window has been created and launched.
    //I believe it has first access to the window object before any child code
    //Note that the parameter is not the true javascript window but only 
    //a chrome wrapper object. The window is window.contentWindow

    //We are going to place an object on the window that the child code will look for
    window.contentWindow.sharedDependencies = {
       shared_dependency: dependency,
       other_shared_dep: dependency2
    }
  });
```

Then as your second page loads, it can check for the property `sharedDependencies`on the window and load them appropriately.

```
//The main module must have the dependency module
angular.module("main_app", ["dependancyModule"]);

var deps = angular.module("dependancyModule", []);

if(typeof window.sharedDependencies === "object")
{
   for(var name in sharedDependencies)
      //Register each dependency as a value because we are receiving 
      //it as a value- not as a factory method or a service method. 
      deps.value(name, sharedDependencies[name]);
}
```

I tried this in a packaged app and it worked however you must deal with calling $apply() manually as changing something in one context will not alert the other context. I have not thought of an elegant solution.

I also am somewhat of a beginner at Angular so this may not support other aspects of Angular. I have not tested it beyond simple bindings to the shared object.

Answer (score 1):

Angular *does not* provide any cross-window support or anything specifically useful for designing local apps. In fact, it doesn't really need to, especially not for Chrome apps.

Check out the localStorage wrapper Google provides for Chrome apps which provides some extra conveniences (e.g. online sync'ing): [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage). You can't use `window.localStorage` as you would in a "normal" web app, so you'll need to utilize it even if you just want the basics of localStorage.

Documentation is a bit sparse, but you will find a tutorial of its usage, including Angular sample code, here: [Save and Fetch Data](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab5_data)

Finally, it would be wise to manage this storage through one or more services, just as you would tend to for AJAX calls / external data resources, in order to encapsulate and reuse across controllers.

**Update:**

As per @Xan's comment below, you can also consider the FileSystem API, which would provide your app with the ability to

> create, read, navigate, and write to a sandboxed section of the user's
>   local file system

Depending on your app's needs, this could be quite useful when working with larger blobs of data, especially when coupled with object storage and `$watch`ers and/or `$interval` polling to detect changes between application instances.

More from [Exploring the FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: One more thing to mention as a storage option is the [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). While no other browser is going to implement it, Chrome advertises it as an API for apps.

Comment: This is a good answer but not for what i am asking. I am looking for sharing angular services amongst separate javascript window objects. Using the chrome app api, `chrome.app.window.create`, I can create a new popup window but i want to communicate in angular between these two windows. There is of course `window.postMessage` but will not work for the level of communication i want.